# Structural Correction requires

Tags: structural-engineering

My contractor did not the work properly on the structure of my house.  He did not support the beam correctly.  I hired an engineer to check it and he sent his recommendation.  I asked my contractor to correct his work as per the drawings and he said he will send his expert to check it.  I was wondering what kind of expert can overule the engineer recommendation? If this expert says that everything is fine, who is responsible?

Comment: "Legal" question such as this can be highly dependent on where you are. Please [edit] your question with this information.

Comment: Likely his expert is an experienced worker. There is not a hierarchy of engineering that someone automatically overrules an engineer.  If the contractor brings in an engineer also, then it will likely boil down to a question of minimally acceptable or not.  This is likely an entirely legal question that isn't appropriate for this venue.

Comment: His expert may be just another engineer on just an experienced person. It's not uncommon in any dispute that both parties get experts to support their positions. This is not an expert overruling another one, because the dispute is among you and the contractor and it can only be settled by agreement between parties or by a court ruling. The kind of court and the details are a matter of law, not a matter of engineering, and strongly depend on the jurisdiction where you are. Maybe you can get some useful advice from http://law.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If a *licensed* civil engineer signs or stamps his calculations, then *he* is liable if his calculations prove to be incorrect.  Licensed engineers are required to carry professional liability insurance specifically to cover that liability.

Hence, if someone else pays for a design, and you are dubious it is adequate, just make sure that the engineer who signed off on it has an active license and insurance policy.  If it fails then you claim against the insurance.